# gcc code::blocks shared library questions

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, codeblocks

I'm using code::blocks on a linux system with the gcc compiler, and I want to be able to use the shared library template to make a shared library with classes, then make another project that accesses that shared library(at compile time, not dynamically) and classes.

I'm sure that code::blocks has simple way of doing this **without** making custom makefiles and manually setting link options, but I don't know how. How do I do this.

## Shared Library

### sl.h

```
class clsClass
{
    public:
    static bool bolReturnTrue(char * chWhatever);
};
```

### sl.cpp

```
bool clsClass::bolReturnTrue(char * chWhatever)
{
    return true;
}
```

## Program Accessing Shared Library

### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    bool Face = clsClass::bolReturnTrue(argv[0]);
    if(Face)
    {
        printf("True.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *acessing the shared lib at compile time*?

Comment: Just a note that you either need to make bolReturnTrue a static method or create an instance of clsClass to call the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have more then one project in your workspace and set [project dependencies](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html), there are no custom makefiles needed.

The basic steps with *Code::Blocks* are the following:

- make sure your shared library project generates an import library *(project properties->build targets)*
- make the shared lib project a dependency of the project in question *(project settings->project dependencies)*
- link to the import library
- include your shared libraries headers in the relevant source files

Comment: Could you be less specific? ;) By the way, i tested it before posting.

Comment: it just won't link, no matter where I add a reference to the library.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to link the dll? You should link to the import library instead (per default .a in code::blocks i believe), it will load the dll for you etc.